# Thread not improving the code performance

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am trying to convert a basic long loop into thread to improve the loop performance.

Here is the threaded version:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

void funcSum(long long int start, long long int end, long long int *sum)
{
    for(auto i = start; i <= end; ++i)
    {
        *sum += i;
    }
}

int main()
{
    long long int start = 10, end = 1900000000;
    long long int sum = 0;
    auto startTime = high_resolution_clock::now();
    thread t1(funcSum, start, end / 2, &sum);
    thread t2(funcSum, end / 2 + 1 , end, &sum);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    auto stopTime = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = duration_cast<seconds>(stopTime - startTime);
    cout << "Sum: " << sum << endl;
    cout << duration.count() << " Seconds";
    return 0;
}
```

And here is the normal code (Without threads):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

void funcSum(long long int start, long long int end, long long int *sum)
{
    for(auto i = start; i <= end; ++i)
    {
        *sum += i;
    }
}

int main()
{
    long long int start = 10, end = 1900000000;
    long long int sum = 0;
    auto startTime = high_resolution_clock::now();
    funcSum(start, end, &sum);
    auto stopTime = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = duration_cast<seconds>(stopTime - startTime);
    cout << "Sum: " << sum << endl;
    cout << duration.count() << " Seconds";
    return 0;
}
```

Sum: 1805000000949999955
5 Seconds
Process finished with exit code 0

In both the cases, time spent is 5 seconds.

Why the first threaded version does not improve the performance? How do I decrease the time using threads for this sum of range?

Comment: you need synchronization when both threads write to `sum`

Comment: also 5 seconds sounds as if you are measuring a non-optimized build. Did you turn on compiler optimizations? Runtimes of debug-builds are close to meaningless

Comment: The actual problem is something else (But this is a close representation). How do I synchronise when both threads write to sum?

Comment: when your code invokes undefined behavior, then the problem is **not** something else. Anything can happen in the presence of ub

Comment: Instead of writing to `sum` from within each thread's loop use a local sum variable and only update the shared variable after the loop (with a lock so that the threads don't mess each other up).

Comment: or simpler: Make each write to a seperate `sum` and add them up only when the threads are joined

Comment: Can anyone of you please share the code snippet of what you explained? I am new to threads.

Comment: btw I have seen compilers transforming such loops into something equivalent to `x = end-start; sum += x*(x+1) / 2` (ie no loop at all), if thats the case here, then adding more threads would result in a slowdown

Comment: please add the compilers version and the compiler flags you used to compile in the question

Comment: I am using gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 and I have turned off compiler optimisations.

Comment: what happens when you turn them on? Measuring runtime with optimizations turned off is like measuring the speed of a car when engine is turned off and you push it with your hands

Comment: It's not very significant in this case but `thread t1(funcSum, start, end / 2, &sum)` should probably be `thread t1(funcSum, start, start + (end-start) / 2, &sum)`

Comment: fwiw, consider that simply putting more threads at a problem rarely results in an immediate speedup. it depends on the problem to be solved. In your particular example using the direct forumla (as in my previous comment) would be the way to go and then adding more threads is not expected to bring an improvment

Comment: You have two threads accessing the same `sum` variable, that won't work very well. You should try having two different sum variables, and adding them together after the threads finish. Also each thread should work out the sum in a local variable, then put the number into the sum variable at the end of the thread.

Comment: @user253751 Can you please share a code snippet of what you have explained?

Comment: ''''
 // fixed threaded version reports Sum: 1805000000949999955 in 2.5 s
 int main()
 {
  long long int start = 10, end = 1900000000;
  long long int sum = 0, sum1 = 0, sum2 = 0;
  auto startTime = high_resolution_clock::now();
  thread t1(funcSum, start, end / 2, &sum1);
  thread t2(funcSum, end / 2 + 1 , end, &sum2);
  t1.join();
  t2.join();
  sum = sum1 + sum2;
  auto stopTime = high_resolution_clock::now();
  auto duration = duration_cast<milliseconds>(stopTime - startTime);
  cout << "Sum: " << sum << endl;
  cout << duration.count() << " ms";
  return 0;
 }
''''

Answer (score 0):

Fixed version of threaded code:

```
// Compute the sum of start ... end
class Summer {
public:
    long long int start;
    long long int end;
    long long int sum = 0;

    Summer(long long int aStart, long long int aEnd)
        : start(aStart),
        end(aEnd)
    {
    }

    void funcSum()
    {
        sum = 0;
        for (auto i = start; i <= end; ++i)
        {
            sum += i;
        }
    }
};

class SummerFunctor {
    Summer& mSummer;
public:
    SummerFunctor(Summer& aSummer)
    : mSummer(aSummer)
    {
    }

    void operator()()
    {
        mSummer.funcSum();
    }
};

// Version with n thread objects reports 
// 1 threads, sum = 1805000000949999955, 1587 ms
// 2 threads, sum = 1805000000949999955, 2547 ms
// 4 threads, sum = 1805000000949999955, 1251 ms
// 6 threads, sum = 1805000000949999955, 916 ms
int main()
{
    long long int start = 10, end = 1900000000;
    long long int sum = 0;
    auto startTime = high_resolution_clock::now();
    const size_t threadCount = 6;

    if (threadCount < 2) {
        funcSum(start, end, &sum);
    } else {
        Summer* summers[threadCount];
        std::thread* threads[threadCount];

        // Start threads
        auto val = start;
        auto partitionSize = (end-start) / threadCount;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < threadCount; ++i) {
            auto partitionEnd = std::min(start + partitionSize, end);
            summers[i] = new Summer(start, partitionEnd);
            start = partitionEnd + 1;
            SummerFunctor functor (*summers[i]);
            threads[i] = new std::thread(functor);
        }

        // Join threads
        for (size_t i = 0; i < threadCount; ++i) {
            threads[i]->join();
            sum += summers[i]->sum;
            delete threads[i];
            delete summers[i];
        }
    }

    auto stopTime = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = duration_cast<milliseconds>(stopTime - startTime);
    cout << threadCount << " threads, sum = " << sum << ", " << duration.count() << " ms" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I had to wrap the Summer object with a functor because std::thread insists on making a copy of a functor handed to it, that we can't access later. The execution gets better when more threads are used (running times see comments). Possible reasons for this:

1. The CPU has to synchronize access to the memory pages even though the threads use separate variables here because the variables likely lie in the same page
2. If there is only one thread running on a CPU, that thread may run at higher CPU frequency, but several threads may run only at normal CPU frequency
3. CPU cores often share arithmetic units
4. Without threads, the compiler can make optimizations that are not possible with threads. In theory, the compiler could unroll the loop and directly print the result.

Comment: With minor code change it's possible to use 'Summer summers[threadCount]' instead of 'Summer* summers[threadCount]' and push_back the new threads into 'std::vector<std::thread> threads', but I see massively degraded performance then. Not sure why.